# Is there a way to write a command directly by code in the immediate window?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to save all lines from the output window into a log-file. That works fine when I enter the command directly into the immediate window. However, I need a way to enter the command line by code.

I searched for a way to enter a command into the immediate window so the log-file I want will be created and filled with data. That's not happening and I don't know if this is even possible. Searching Google didn't help so far.

My command line is:

```
> Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput C:\Users\user\AppData\test.log
```

And I try to get it into the immediate window by

```
Debug.Print("> Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput C:\Users\user\AppData\test.log")
```

The command line works fine when put directly into the immediate window (either by typing it in or pasting it in). When I try to do that by code, nothing happens. Is there a way to do that or do I have to try another option and if so, what option is it?

EDIT:
I've tried the solution provided by RobertBaron with the following changes:

```
'Dim dummy = $"C:\\log\\outputfileAddOn_{Date.Now:yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss}.log"
'cmdWindow.SendInput($"Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput {dummy}", True)
cmdWindow.SendInput("Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput C:\log\outputfile_AddOn.log", True)
```

(I want a new file to be written every time, so I tried to add the date at the end to have unique file names)
It creates the file but doesn't log anything in it. What do I do wrong?

Another solution I have found was to add a command parameter in project-properties-debug-command parameter:

```
> C:\log\outputfile.log
```

This creates the file and inserts all of the data from the output window. The only problem that I have now is that this file will be overwritten every time the program is started. Is there a way I can set the logging from the second, third, … start at the end of the file? (adding /on at the end of the command Parameter didn't help) Or can I provide something like "outputfile_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss.log" (for example: outputfile_2019_07_23_15_47_45.log)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you just want to save the output window content you can do that from within visual studio itself.

Comment: @sidprasher I'm sorry for this (maybe) silly question, but how do I do that?

Comment: If you are in the output window - then the `File` menu has an entry called `Save Output As...`

Comment: @sidprasher Is there an option to save the output automatically?

Comment: When you say _I need a way to enter the command line by code_, where is that code running? In VS debugger? In an external application?

Comment: @RobertBaron It is running in VS debugger, but the person testing the programm in debug mode isn't really good with VS (we are trying to find some bugs and everyone is helping), so I need the output file being saved automatically during testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Visual Studio Extension project.

[image]

Add a new Custom Command item to the VSIX project.

[image]

This will create the `Command1.vb`. This is where you implement the code that you want to execute inside Visual Studio. The code executes whenever you select the entry `Invoke Command1` from the `Tools` menu.

At the bottom of the `Command1.vb` file, there is the `Execute()` `Sub`. It displays a message just to show that the command is working. You can remove this eventually. But for now, just run the project. Another instance of Visual Studio will start. This is where you can test and debug your code. Once the second instance of Visual Studio has started, go to its `Tools` menu, and select the `Invoke Command1` entry. A message box will display. Stop execution.

Now we want to modify the `Execute()` `Sub` so that our code gets executed when `Invoke Command1` is selected. Here is the `Sub` that will execute the command that you want. Add it to the `Command1` class.

```
Public Sub ExecCommandWindow()
    Dim dte As EnvDTE.DTE = CType(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.GetGlobalService(GetType(Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SDTE)), EnvDTE.DTE)
    Dim cmdWindow As CommandWindow = CType(dte.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindCommandWindow).Object, CommandWindow)
    'Display some text in the command window
    cmdWindow.OutputString("Executing command from the automation OM...")
    'Send some command strings to the command window and execute them...
    'This command will start logging all input/output in the command window to the specified file
    cmdWindow.SendInput("Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput cmdwindow.log", True)

    ''Open a file in a code editor:
    ''  1. We use an alias, 'of', for the File.OpenFile command
    ''  2. This command takes quote-delimited parameters (in this case,
    ''     the name of the editor to load the file in)
    'Dim cmd As String = "of "
    'cmd = (cmd + """""C:\Contoso\ContosoCommonFramework\Integration.cs""""")
    'cmd = (cmd + "/e:""""CSharp Editor""""")
    'cmdWindow.SendInput(cmd, True)
    'cmdWindow.SendInput("Edit.Find MessageTrxId", True)

    'Turn off logging
    cmdWindow.SendInput("Tools.LogCommandWindowOutput /off", True)
End Sub
```

Change the `Execute()` `Sub` to call `ExecCommandWindow()`.

You can change the name of the command by changing its title in the `Command1` class.

The Visual Studio extension needs to be installed by each user. Just distribute the `.vsix` file. To install, double-click it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed guide! I am currently trying to create the Project. Just for clarification - I redirect the output from the output window to the immediate window where I can save the output in a file with the command above. Is this also working with your solution? Do I get the data from the output window? Thank you!

Comment: @LiliumCandidum - Yes, the call to `cmdWindow.SendInput()` is just like typing the command in the immediate window. You can execute any command that you would normally type.

Comment: I've tried your solution with a few changes (path and file Name). The file will be created every time I start my program, but there is no data in it.

Comment: @LiliumCandidum - What did you try exactly? You ran your program in the Experimental instance?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I did. I edited my post above with all the information I gained so far.

Comment: @LiliumCandidum - I read your update but you are not very clear about what you did exactly. Please, list the steps you did. It is more efficient for you to tell what you did than me asking you!

Comment: I followed your guide step by step and just changed the lines I showed in my update. And I have tested it in the experimental instance.

Comment: @LiliumCandidum - Ok, so you started your program in the experimental instance of VS,your program wrote to the output window, and then you selected the Tools -> Invoke Command1 menu entry in the experimental instance? Is that what you did?

Comment: Yes, That's what I did. I am sorry, I was busy working on another project. At the moment, I collect the data with the command parameter ">> C:\log\outputfile.log" This attaches every log at the end of the file. It's not the best solution, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best solution, but it works (for now):

adding

```
>> C:\log\outputfile.log
```

(with two '>' before the path for the log file) attaches every log at the end of the file. So I get all Information and nothing is being overwritten.

As I want to know if there is a better solution, I will keep this thread open if that is permitted.